# Running Supervisor on Heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-sqs, supervisord

I was wondering if anyone knows how to run Supervisor on Heroku to manage queue workers? I've managed to get [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) running locally for my Laravel app, but have no idea how to create more worker processes to go through the job queue quicker.

I asked Heroku's support on this and they said it should work, but they don't have any documentation for this, nor do I think they would want to help figure this out for me. Currently the only way to get more workers on a queue (I'm using SQS) is to create more processes through the Procfile which you have to pay for additional dynos, or scale up if you're on the performance dynos.

Seems kinda inefficient for me as my current worker process only uses up < 60MB working through the queue, and the memory limit of the hobby dynos are 512MB. It's a waste to spin up more dynos when the existing dynos are underutilized.

I've googled for hours but haven't been able to find a solution to this.

Is this even possible in the first place? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I think I've managed to figure out the solution. I've posted it on my blog - http://www.dannytalk.com/running-supervisor-with-laravel-workers-on-heroku/.

Comment: Awesome! That saved me the same hours on google that you were facing. Only issue I'm having is that the supervisord process isn't started automatically, even though it's in the Procfile and the supervisor task is identified during the deployment. I can start supervisord manually from a console session and the workers are spawned fine, I just can't figure out the auto-start, the supervisor task is totally ignored, nothing in the log - any clues on where to look for what might be happening there?

Comment: Your site returns an error now. "Error thrown
Call to a member function id() on array"

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to go with a docker image that has supervisor in it.